# Watch all files with gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

Currently i have folder stucture like below.

- css

  - scss

    - _icon.scss
    - _admin.scss
  - main.scss
  - personal.scss
- modules

  - directives

    - map

      - map.html
      - map.scss
      - map.js

I have gulp sass with  following

```
gulp.task("sass", function() {
    return gulp.src('css/main.scss') // location of main scss file name
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //TODO: important, comment out this line in staging and production
        //.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'})) // include this to rename the file to fileName.min.css
        //.pipe(minifycss()) // include this to minify the file
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) //TODO: important, comment out this line in staging and production
        .pipe(concat("main.min.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

I want to watch all files with extension `.scss` in my root directory when there are any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your 'sass' task compiles it correctly, then you just need a watch task to run that task automatically.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['./**/*.scss'], ['sass'])
});
```

Make it run automatically when you run `gulp` by adding it to a 'default' task ....

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch'])
```

https://gulpjs.com/

Comment: with this you `recompile` the entire glob match every file change. don't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a gulp plugin to allow incremental caching with node sass.

give it a try:
https://github.com/hitmands/gulp-sass-pedigree